# No build time for new build system in Sublime Text 3

Tags: build, sublimetext3

I successfully added python3 as a new build system as follows:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I couldn't get any build time output in python3 system but I can in other build systems. Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see a build time is that you're specifying `-i` as an argument to `python3`. That makes it interactive, but there is no way to actually provide it any input because Sublime doesn't let you interact with a running program; it just lets you start it and wait for it to finish. As such, you're not getting any build time because the build goes on forever and never actually stops.

As a verification, note that the last thing that's presented in the output panel is the `>>>` prompt of the interactive interpreter, where it's waiting for input that you can't provide. Additionally the `Tools > Cancel Build` remains available, and selecting it terminates the build (although in this case is doesn't tell you how long it was running). That command is disabled if there's not a build running.

One way to fix your problem would be to remove the `-i` from your `cmd` entry above. Alternatively, you could use a version of the `Python.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime, modified to run `python3` instead of `python`:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python3 -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```